# Find limit by summation of series or by using Cauchy's first limit theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, cauchy-sequences

[image]

I have to find the limit of this problem I have found that problem like this I always get two answers one by using the Cauchy first limit theorem and second by definite integral method so I am confused as to use which method can I not apply Cauchy theorem on this problem are there some conditions that I am overlooking.

This is a in general problem not specific problem. Please explain this to me

Comment: Can you write the Cauchy first limit theorem in its general form

Comment: Google it bro. It is a very famous theorem and fundamental for limits

Comment: See my answer just confusion with the indices

Answer (score 2):

The theorem you're referring to says : if $x_n\to l$ then $y_n=\sum_i^nx_i/n\to l$. Now if $x_n=n^2/(n^2+n^2)$ then

$$y_n={\sum_{i=1}{i^2\over i^2+i^2}\over n}\neq {\sum_{i=1}^n{n^2\over n^2+i^2}\over n}$$

So you're just confused with the indices

Comment: Thanks and I apologize I was rude

Comment: Don't worry ! When you have a problem like this one, write down the theorem in its general form and then apply it step by step. You will sort it out by yourself